# Can characteristic polynomials of matrices be used for something unrelated to eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm teaching at high school level and will be teaching (very basic) linear algebra for the second time soon. One thing I'm focussing on this time (generally, not just in linear algebra) is to avoid teaching a concept only because the concept is "tradition". What I'm trying to do is to use every concept in multiple, different contexts, so my students see their diversity (and of course I'm hoping every student will find at least one context interesting).

In a first linear algebra course, most students will use the determinant to write down the characteristic polynomial of a matrix and its roots are the eigenvalues for the matrix. Linear maps have a broad range of applications and so do their eigenvalues. It feels to me like the concept of the characteristic polynomial must be useful for other things too.

**Q:** Are there any other ways to use the characteristic polynomial for a matrix that might be suited for a first introduction?

Answer (score 2):

Well, it can be used to *characterize* matrices. After all, similar matrices will have the same characteristic polynomial. Since trace and determinant occur as coefficients, yo may simply view the characteristic polynomial as a means to efficiently encode these two invariants, together with a few more (if $n>2$)

Answer (score 0):

Cayley Hamilton theorem is such a result.

Consider an $n \times n$ matrix $A$. Through Cayley Hamilton theorem which says that if $C(\lambda)$ is the characteristic polynomial of $A$, then $C(A)=0$, it allows to express any polynomial in $A$ as a polynomial with degree at most $n-1$.

For example if $\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&3\end{pmatrix}$, with $C(\lambda)= \lambda^2-3\lambda+2$, we have $A^2=3A-2I \ (1) $; thus any polynomial in $A$ such as $A^5+3A^2+A+I$, can be transformed, through sequential applications of (1) into the form $aA+B$.

$A^5+3A^2+A+I=(A^2)(A(A^2)+3I)+A+I=(3A-2I)(A(3A-2I)+3I)=(3A-2I)(9A-6I-2A+3I)+A+I=...$

Comment: To the question asker: If you're wanting some source material with this and related concepts to draw from, I have a book that I acquired fairly recently called Matrix Theory by F. R. Gantmacher that covers it and much more. I doubt it'd suitable for your students, but you might it useful as a source of ideas. I got the book because I found it at a bargain at a local book store, and had wanted a good book on the theory of matrices themselves (I knew much more about linear maps and vector spaces than the matrix side of linear algebra). There are actually 2 vols, but the 1st is what I have.

Comment: @Justin Benfield Yes this is a very valuable book, very well written (and well translated from Russian). Its drawback : it has been written 50 years ago ; thus, some methods are outdated, some others, like SVD, not considered. On my side, I would advise "Linear Algebra"  by G. Strang, either as a book or as tutorials on [OCW of MIT](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06-linear-algebra-spring-2010/)